# Jmeter assert json response element to be NOT NULL

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am getting Json response, I have parsed it using *jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor* and got an element say 'Access_Token'. This Access_Token is dynamic. So I just want to make sure that this element is ***not null*.**

Any leads would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

1. In the [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) provide **Default Value**, for example `NOT_FOUND`

   [image: JSON Path Extractor]
2. Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) **after** the JSON Path Extractor and configure it as follows:

   - **Apply To**: JMeter Variable -> `Access_Token`
   - **Pattern Matching Rules**:

     - Tick `NOT`
     - Tick `Equals`
   - **Patterns to Test**: `NOT_FOUND` (or whatever you entered into the "Default Value" input of the JSON Path Extractor)

     [image: Response Assertion]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for comprehensive information on using Assertions in JMeter scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) component after you get your Access_Token and in it check what you want...

```
if (vars.get("Access_Token") != null) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Depending on your needs, you can do basically what ever you want from here. For example stop the thread, stop the test...

Comment: Is there any way achieving this using -  jp@gc - JSON Path Assertion @Ivan Markovic

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, but Beanshell will work if you go with it...

Answer (score 1):

Since JMeter 3.0 there is a new JSON Path Processor that you should use instead of the JMeter Plugins one.

See its features in action here:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/easy-scripting-of-json-applications-with-apache-jmeter/

You can then apply Dmitri T. answer.

Answer (score 0):

In jmeter 5 you could try doing something like this:

[image: JSON Assertion]